# Updating a subscription schedule with Stripe java APIs

Tags: java, stripe-payments

After a completed check session that contains recurring prices I have attached a schedule to the subscription created by Stripe.

I am now trying to update that schedule to set the iteration count on its single phase, and the API is making this extremely clumsy... am I missing something?

The method below is a webhook handler that receives the current schedule; the update request seems to require SubscriptionScheduleUpdateParams inner classes, meaning I have to manually reconstruct the phases, their items, their prices and so on using Params classes: is there any better way??

```
 // case "subscription_schedule.created" -> configureSchedule(event, (SubscriptionSchedule) stripeObject);
 private void configureSchedule(Event event, SubscriptionSchedule schedule)
 {
    Phase phase = schedule.getPhases().get(0);

    // All I need is to set that phase's iteration count, but:
    SubscriptionScheduleUpdateParams params =
                SubscriptionScheduleUpdateParams.builder().
                        setApplicationFeePercent(phase.getApplicationFeePercent()).
                        // ... set 10 other properties :( 
                        addPhase(SubscriptionScheduleUpdateParams.Phase.builder().
                                addAllItem(SubscriptionScheduleUpdateParams.Phase.Item.builder().
                                             // again manual transfer of each item property
 }
```

Am I missing something about those APIs? I can't find any bridge between the objects/classes sent by webhooks and the ones required in update requests.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Stripe requires you to send the current and any/all future phases so using params is the right way to go about it: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules#updating